# phppgadmin error "No server supplied!"

Tags: phppgadmin

facing error "No server supplied!" while uploading file having 789.3 MB in phppgadmin. please let me know how can i resolve it.

i have updated php.ini with below upload_max_filesize

upload_max_filesize = 1024M

Comment: i solved this issue by resizing below parameters in php.in 
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M

Comment: i tryed your parameters in php.ini, this didnt work for me.